# Random array not working as the expected

Tags: php, arrays, random

I'm trying to create an array and display some random values. I'm using the following code:

```
$range = range(10,31);
$rand = array_rand($range,5);
shuffle($rand);

foreach ($rand as $number) {
  $number = (str_pad($number, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT));
  echo $number." ";
}
```

I want to generate numbers between 10 and 31 and display 5 of them, but my code still generating numbers between 00 and 31. Why this is happening?

Comment: `array_rand` returns the keys, not the values.

Comment: Why are you calling `shuffle` when `array_rand()` already returns a randomly shuffled result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `array_rand()` returns keys, not values, you have to use them as indexes into the original `$range` array.

```
foreach ($rand as $index) {
  $number = (str_pad($range[$index], 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT));
  echo $number." ";
}
```

You could also just call `shuffle($range)` and then iterate over the first 5 elements of `$range`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print 5 random numbers between 10 and 30 why not create a range of [10, 31] call shuffle on it, then print only 5 numbers?

```
$arr = range(10, 31);
shuffle($arr);
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; ++$i) {
echo $arr[$i] . "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

range creates an array from 10 to 31, assigning them from key [0] to [21]. array_rand returns the KEY of random entries. try this:

```
for ($1=10,$i<32,$i++)
 {$range[$i] = 1;}
```

that should give you an array with KEYS from 10 to 31, then it might work :)